# How to create a timelined Flash animation without using .fla only ActionScript?

Tags: flash

Any sample ActionScript code on the net available ?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? This is rather vague. Do you mean importing individual frame images and displaying them in a sequence?

Comment: Do you wanna use flash at all?

Comment: I only want to use free tools like flex sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use fl.motion package, use tweening engines instead! Such as [Greensock Tweening Platform](http://www.greensock.com/v11/), [GTween](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/) etc. It's free, well documented and has high perfomance. Just look at [Greensock's main page](http://www.greensock.com/) header, its animations made with pure ActionScript 3.

Comment: Remember to check the license for Greesock - it's only free if you're using it for a public website or a free game/app

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a look at the [fl.motion package](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/motion/package-detail.html)

It includes actionscript classes that implement the keyframe/tween-based animation that the Flash IDE uses.

You can define the movement either directly with actionscript or using an XML-based syntax.

There are some simple examples in the Adobe documentation in the link.

Comment: Thank you but I guess I need a flash license to use them ?

Comment: Yes, you need a flash license to use the fl.motion package. If you need a non-adobe solution, I've heard good things about Greensock, as suggested by Ninja in their answer